# BITBUCKET - share repo or transfer repo

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have private repo on bitbucket.
I want to share code but I don't know difference between :

- share repo from my account with another user
- transfer repo to team repo and then add other users

Of course, I guess url will change for "pull" and "push" actions if I transfer repo

But is there another difference ? What is the best way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference whether or not you stick with an individual account or migrate to a team account, other than the change in the remote URL.

The main benefit of going with a team account it is easier to manage roles, access and members of the team can work on all the team's repos. Think of team as a company account where all the employees may/may not see and can/can't work on any of the projects. While as an individual account, you are just collaborating with up to 4 other people on YOUR project.

Outside of that, they are identical. Though, if you want more than 5 total people working on a private repo, you do need to make a team account and change your plan accordingly.